# Unsplash api like a specific photo

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, axios

I have some issues related to the unsplash api that I havent solved yet.

Im currently creating a function to like a photo from unsplash with client account.

The url for the post request is: POST /photos/:id/like?client_id=My_client_id.

However, when I executed this request, it returned me the 401 error.
Can someone help me? Thank you so much?

P/s: here is my code:

```js
 const url = `https://api.unsplash.com/photos/${image.id}/like`;
            axios.post(url, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: "Client-ID my_client_id_here"
                }
            }).then(photo => {
                console.log('like photo')
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error(error)
            })
```

Comment: can we see some code plz?

Comment: I've just edited the question...

Comment: 401 is Invalid Access Token
May be Authorization: Client-ID YOUR_ACCESS_KEY

Comment: So basically, the request is not available if I use client_id? Must I use access_key?

Answer (score 0):

like photo action should be need user authentication, not public authentication. you need use unsplash oauth to get the access token.
detail in [enter link description here](https://unsplash.com/documentation/user-authentication-workflow)